# ProFTPd unable to seteuid

Tags: ubuntu, root, webmin, proftpd

i'm trying to figure out this problem:

```
2014-04-07 14:00:58,628 srv proftpd[10143] srv (pfsense.localdomain[192.168.0.1]): FTP session opened.
2014-04-07 14:01:13,779 srv proftpd[10091] srv (pfsense.localdomain[192.168.0.1]): Preparing to chroot to directory '/srv/user1'
2014-04-07 14:01:13,779 srv proftpd[10091] srv (pfsense.localdomain[192.168.0.1]): USER user1: Login successful.
2014-04-07 14:01:13,779 srv proftpd[10091] srv (pfsense.localdomain[192.168.0.1]): ROOT PRIVS: unable to seteuid(): Operation not permitted
2014-04-07 14:01:13,779 srv proftpd[10091] srv (pfsense.localdomain[192.168.0.1]): ROOT PRIVS: unable to setegid(): Operation not permitted
2014-04-07 14:01:13,782 srv proftpd[10091] srv (pfsense.localdomain[192.168.0.1]): RELINQUISH PRIVS: unable to seteuid(PR_ROOT_UID): Operation not permitted
2014-04-07 14:01:13,782 srv proftpd[10091] srv (pfsense.localdomain[192.168.0.1]): FTP session closed.
```

I have made a folder on my filesystem 'srv' with sub folders like 'user1', 'user2' and so on.

```
drwxrwxrwx  19 root root  4096 Mar  5 20:05 srv
```

Each user has their home directoty set to 'user1', 'user2' and so on.

```
drwx---r-x 189 user1   users     4096 Apr  3 11:34 user1
```

proftp conf:

```
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf
ServerName          "SRV"
ServerType standalone
DeferWelcome            off
MultilineRFC2228 on
DefaultServer           on
ShowSymlinks on
TimeoutNoTransfer 600
TimeoutStalled 600
TimeoutIdle 1200
DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir .message true
ListOptions "-l"
DenyFilter          \*.*/
DefaultRoot         ~
Port                21
User                proftpd
Group               nogroup
Umask 022 022
AllowOverwrite          on
TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
 QuotaEngine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
 Ratios off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_delay.c>
 DelayEngine on
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
 ControlsEngine        off
 ControlsMaxClients    2
 ControlsLog           /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
 ControlsInterval      5
 ControlsSocket        /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
 AdminControlsEngine off
</IfModule>
Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/
<Global>
 PassivePorts 65400 65535
</Global>
```

More:

```
Ubuntu server 13.10
Webmin 1.680
ProFTPD Version 1.3.5rc3
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and corrected it by setting UseIPv6 to off in /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf